# How to setup edit and add views with a hasOne relationship in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, view, media, has-one

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I am using cakePHP 1.3 and I am having trouble getting the edit view to update the main Model and a hasOne related Model. I am fairly positive this has to do with my setup of the edit.ctp view. I am using the media plugin which I got working on another model, so I don't believe that has anything to do with that. Specifically I am working on getting the Media Plugin, Monolithic Attachment Model with a hasOne relationship working.

I have checked out the cake docs
http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo  
read the majority of the docs in the Media Plugin this like is the most relevant
https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/next/docs/RECIPES

and spent extensive time searching google.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

James

### Model - client.php

```
<?php
class Client extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Client';
var $displayField = 'name';
var $actsAs = array(
    'Media.Transfer',
    'Media.Coupler',
    'Media.Generator'
);

[...]
var $hasOne = array(
  'Logo' => array(
      'className' => 'Attachment',
      'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
      'conditions' => array('Logo.model' => 'Client'),
      'dependent' => true,
));
[...]
?>
```

### Controller - clients_controller.php

```
<?php
class ClientsController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Clients';
    [...]
function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid client', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Client->saveAll($this->data, array('validate'=>'first') )) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The client has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The client could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Client->recursive = 0;
        $this->data = $this->Client->read(null, $id);
    }
    $statuses = $this->Client->Status->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('statuses'));
}
    [...]
    ?>
```

### View - edit.ctp

```
<h1><?php __('Edit Clients');?></h1>
<div class="clients form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Client', array('type' => 'file'))."\n";?>
<fieldset>
<?php
   echo $this->Form->input('Client.id')."\n";
   echo $this->Form->input('Client.name')."\n";
   echo $this->Form->input('Client.address1')."\n";
   echo $this->Form->input('Client.address2')."\n";
   [...]
   echo $form->input('Logo.id')."\n";
   echo $form->input('Logo.file', array('type' => 'file'))."\n";
   echo $form->hidden('Logo.foreign_key')."\n";
   echo $form->hidden('Logo.model', array('value' => 'Client'))."\n";
    ?>
</fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
```

### clients sql

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime default NULL,
  `modified` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

### attachments sql

```
CREATE TABLE `attachments` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `foreign_key` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `dirname` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `basename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `checksum` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `alternative` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `created` datetime default NULL,
  `modified` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Are the fields on the form showing the data as expected? What is happening when you hit submit? Are either of the records being updated? Does saveAll() return false? Are there any validation errors? ($this->Client->validationErrors)

Comment: The primary Model is being updated, but nothing is happening with the hasOne.

Comment: Can you post your schema for clients and logos?

Comment: I've had unexpected behaviour when associations aren't registered from both directions. I'm not familiar with these plugins but perhaps you need to bind logo to client on the fly with a belongsTo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses. I finally got it working. It appears that for some reason the saveAll was causing me grief. When I saved the Client then saved the Logo everything worked.

I posted the code below.

### Controller Code

```
function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid client', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $client = $this->Client->save($this->data);
        if (!empty($client)) {            
            $this->data['Logo']['foreign_key'] = $this->Client->id;
            $this->data['Logo']['model'] = 'Client';
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The client has been saved', true));
            $this->Client->Logo->save($this->data);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The client could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Client->recursive = 0;
        $this->data = $this->Client->read(null, $id);
    }
    $statuses = $this->Client->Status->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('statuses'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var $hasOne = array(
  'Logo' => array(
      'className' => 'Attachment',
      'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key', // 'foreign_key' ? is that a name for your fk?
      'conditions' => array('Logo.model' => 'Client'),
      'dependent' => true,
));
```

here you haven't defined the foreign_key which binds your logo to your client. look up in your database for the foreign key and put it's name here.

Comment: Yeah the name of foreign key is foreign_key. I am using one table attachments to keep track of the uploads, which is why the foreign_key field is so generic sounding. If you look at the Model client.ctp it calls it out in the hasOne declaration.